# Given a string how can I remove all the duplicated consecutive letters?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension

How can I remove double consecutive letters from a string?

For instance:

```
a_str = 'hii thherre'
```

should become

```
'hi there'
```

I tried to do:

```
a_str = ''.join(sorted(set(a_str), key=a_str.index))
```

However, I am getting:

```
'hi ter'
```

Comment: What about triple or quadruple consecutive letters?

Comment: The task was removing double consecutive letters, but the code you've written is to remove all but the very first appearance of a letter. You should put more effort into solving this yourself; SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: @timgeb, yes that could be also considered

Comment: and what if a word actually has double letters? For example `three` instead of `threee`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> yes that [triple or quadruple consecutive letters] could  be also considered

In that case, if I understand correctly, you just want to take one of every sequence of consecutive equal letters. Consider [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a_str = 'hii thherre'
>>> ''.join(k for k, _ in groupby(a_str))
'hi there'
```

edit: bonus regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1*', r'\1', a_str)
'hi there'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by iterating over combinations of all characters and their next elements and selecting ones that aren't equal.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a_str = 'hii thherre'
new_a = ''.join(i[0] for i in zip_longest(a_str, a_str[1:]) if i[0] != i[1])

print(new_a) # -> hi there
```

Comment: Took me a second to figure out why it had to be `zip_longest` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Straight python with no imports,

Split the string and check if the next char is the same, if it is, remove it.

```
a_str = 'hii thherre'
e = list(a_str)
b_str = ""
for i, x in enumerate(e):
    nextelem = e[(i + 1) % len(e)]
    if nextelem == x:
        print("Duplicate found, removing")
    else:
        b_str = b_str + x

print(b_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pure Python version, functional style:

```
import operator

getter = operator.itemgetter(1)
it = iter(s)
result = next(it) + ''.join(map(getter, filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], zip(s, it))))
```

Or, avoiding the import:

```
it = iter(s)
result = next(it) + ''.join(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], zip(s, it))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, using *for-loop* with *if-condition*:

```py
a_str = 'hii thherre'
s = a_str[0]
for i in range(1, len(a_str)):
    if(a_str[i-1] != a_str[i]): s += a_str[i]
print(s) #hi there
```